# Вычисление необходимого количество информации

Tags: информатика, системы-счисления

Какое минимальное количество бит понадобится для того, чтобы закодировать все натуральные числа не превышающие числа 576 в 8-ричной С-С

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log<sub>2</sub>( 576<sub>base 8</sub> ) ≈ 8.577428828…

Девяти бит будет достаточно.

**На пальцах, способ первый:**
576 в восьмеричной — это 382 в десятичной. В двоичной системе число 382<sub>10</sub> займет log<sub>2</sub>( 382 ) знаков (округляем до целого сверху). Поскольку степени двойки хотя бы до шестнадцатой программист обязан знать наизусть, то видно сразу, что 382 больше, чем 256 — то есть 8 бит недостаточно, но меньше, чем 512 — то есть в девять бит поместится.

**На пальцах, способ второй:**
Каждое восьмеричная цифра — это три двоичных цифры, очень удобно. То есть двузначное восьмеричное полностью поместится в шестизначном двоичном. Дальше смотрим: первой цифрой пятерка, это 5<sub>8</sub> = 101<sub>2</sub>, оп! в два двоичных разряда уже не помещаемся. Значит, нужно еще три, всего девять двоичных цифр. А вот числа до 377<sub>8</sub> поместились бы в восьми битах, потому что 3<sub>8</sub> = 11<sub>2</sub>, на запись старшей цифры достаточно двух бит.

Comment: да ответ такой, но я не понял log2(576 base 8) ≈ 8.577428828… base это как? как нашли?

Comment: Щаз дополню ответ.

Comment: спасибо огромное, второй способ еще пытаюсь понять, но первый да)))чет я неподумал насчет 10 С-С

Comment: извените а можете обьяснить
 А вот числа до 3778 поместились бы в восьми битах, потому что 38 = 112, на запись старшей цифры достаточно двух бит. (но ведь тогда 3(цифры)*2=6 а не 8)

Comment: посмоторите еще вопрос http://hashcode.ru/questions/33436/%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F тоже по системе счисления

Comment: 377<sub>8</sub> — только старший разряд поместится в двух битах. А семерки — нет. То есть достаточно 2 + 2*3 = 8 бит.

Comment: Второй вопрос посмотрел, ответил.